# GCE: Block direct HTTP/S access. However, should only be available through N/W Loadbalancer

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

We are in the process of configuring and hosting our services on Google Cloud Services. We are using few instances of GCE. We also have a network load balancer. What I want to do is to block all direct HTT/S requests to individual instances and only be available via N/W load balancer.

Also, N/W load balancer will be mapped to a DNS.

Answer (score 0):

By default GCE will not allow any ports be accessible from outside the network unless you create a firewall rule to allow.

One way is to remove the external IP for all the instances and use only one server as gateway instance with external IP to go to all the other instances. Make sure you add firewall rule allowing access from intended source to the gateway instance. This way only gateway instance is exposed to intended sources or external world based on firewall rule. 
Then you can create network load balancer adding up instances that have no direct external access.

This is one way these are more ways to achieve.

Comment: Ok. I tried blocking HTTP access to VM's and have a load balancer for these VM's. It didnt work. Your suggestion is having a VM on top of instances which really acts like a gateway. On top load balancer sits? In which case, are we not loosing the advantage of having the Load Balancer?

Comment: Don't block HTTP access. Remove the external IP assigned to the instance. Re-enable the HTTP access firewall rule.

Comment: Ok. I have 2 GCE for which I have disabled External IP. HTTP access is still active. Load Balancer sits in top of these. Doesn't work. Now page loads, however takes significant amount of time to load. Any clue why is that? If re-enable external IP, page load is instant.